# how many kilometers can i do on 25L of fuel

Tags: problem-solving

someone please help me .. my fuel gauge is not accurate and i need to know how many kilometers i can do on a full tank which is 25L

50922km was what it was on when I filled 18L of petrol.
the next time I filled up the car it was at 51064km and I put 15 and a half liters..

so I figured out that I did 142km between those two times filling it up (51064km-50922km=142km) .. but I need to know how many kms for a FULL tank of petrol .. helppp!

Comment: so correct me if im wrong here ...

Comment: so correct me if im wrong here ...
18-25=7L so say I had about 5L left in the tank coz I don't think I got it full to the brim time before last, then I put 18L in, it does 142km before I (think) its empty again and I put 15L to the brim .. that means I still had about 10 L still in the tank from that 18L so does that mean I just need to work out how many kms I do per L of fuel .. anyone help???

Answer (score 1):

ok, so assuming that you filled it completely when you put the $18L$, and you filled it completely when you put the $15.5L$, then that means that you spent a total of $15.5L$ (what you reloaded) to drive the difference, $142Km$. That means that on average you spent $142Km/15.5L=9.47$ Km per liter. So on average a liter drives you a little less than $9$ and a half kilometers, if you want to know how far that takes you, we multiply: $9.47*25=236.7 Km$.

Comment: are you sure about that? 236 km seems like a bit much for a mini clubman

Comment: according to the numbers you gave, this should be correct

Comment: well im not good at maths, hense why I am asking smart people, I edited my question .. how I came to get 142km .. I don't even know if that is right the way I worked that out

Comment: In practice, the "full" level is not all that precise (especially if you're rounding to the half-litre), and your fuel consumption will depend on driving conditions.  So I wouldn't trust these numbers well enough to go on a 236 km trip on a road with no gas stations....

Comment: so I should just stick with a close number of say 200kms? would that be the best option?